# Terraform local-exec Powershell in Azure DevOps error: Run Connect-AzAccount to login

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to automate Azure resource creation using out-of-the-box Terraform via Azure DevOps, but for some parts I need Powershell. That's fine, as there is this local-exec thing I can use.

The Powershell scripts work fine when I run them locally on Terraform, but running everything from Azure DevOps I get this login error: Run Connect-AzAccount to login

I have a DevOps service principal running the release definition, but it seems the context of the Terraform process is not propagated to the execution of the Powershell script?

I don't want to extract the Powershell stuff from the Terraform script, to run it as a separate DevOps task as this is one of the sequence steps of my deployment.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whose task you are using for Terraform, but I am able to do the following in my externally called PowerShell script:

```
$subscriptionId = $env:ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
$tenantId = $env:ARM_TENANT_ID
$clientId = $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID
$secret = $env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
```

I'm using the az cli, so I then run this command

```
az.cmd login --service-principal --username $clientId --password $secret --tenant $tenantId --output none
```

But you should be able to also run:

```
$securesecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object pscredential($clientId,$securesecret)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenantId -ServicePrincipal
Select-AzSubscription $subscriptionId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed works! To make it not too easy for me you added a typo in ConvertTo-SecureString ;-)

Comment: @Jean-PaulSmit Doh!! : )  Fixed.